# Delete old workspace from TFS VS2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, tfs, workspace

I'm trying to remove workspace from people who actual not working anymore, and have a problem.

**What I'm doing. (CMD from VS)**

```
tf.exe workspace /delete workspacename;owner /server:
serveraddress - where is workspacename=WORKSPACE, owner=ThatUsername, and serveraddress = myfulltfs adress
```

When I **hit enter**, get the **message**:

**`Specify one workspace`**

I am 100% that I'm using **real data**.

Answer (score 1):

Not an exact answer to your problem but I've always found its easier to use the TFS Sidekick tool for this.

http://www.attrice.info/cm/tfs/

Comment: I tryed out, but.. TF204017: The operation cannot be completed because the user (Name Lastname) does not have one or more required permissions (Use) for workspace MYMACHINE;Name Lastname. I can guarantee that im admin on this machine.

Comment: Googling, i found it that its up to MS issue that need to fix it in next upates i think.. : https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/48d38556-32cb-4214-a849-a51cc148ea23/cant-access-visual-studio-online-after-switching-from-visual-studio-2015-enterprise-to-visual?forum=TFService

Answer (score 0):

According to the message info. It seems you are using the wrong username of the owner. So **the command can't recognize the workspace**. Try to use the username that the user use to login in TFS. Usually it's the **domain name**.

*Also note **there is no space** between `workspacename`&`;`&`owner name`*  .

**Don't use the owner name of the workspace.** The owner of the workspace is not equal the Domain username.

Comment: I tryed, before i use this command, tf workspaces /owner:* /computer:TEST1 /collection:http://tfs2013:8080/tfs/sw

Comment: I‘m afraid the owner of the workspace is not equal the Domain username. Tried with the owner name of the workspace in my computer. Get the same result :"Specify one workspace " . However, change to use the domain username , everything works fine.

Comment: That old username i want to delete, is not anymore at AD. So it bothering me, i cant get latest on that location. huh still didnt fix it.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the quotation marks "":

```
tf.exe workspace /delete "workspacename;owner"
```